# Timeout and raise when using .click

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, timeout

I'm trying to disable the timeout alert in an instruction and pass a timeout parameter:

```
Driver.FindElementById("ctl01_lnkCharacter", 5000, False).Click
```

I tried the below too, the same situation happens

```
Driver.FindElementById("ctl01_lnkCharacter", timeout:=5000, raise:=False).Click
```

The timeout parameters (5000) and raise for not to alert in case of timeout (`False`) are ignored. It uses the default timeout parameter, or if it has passed the parameter explicitly before, this value is assumed.

I tested passing the different parameter above to test:

```
Driver.Timeouts.PageLoad = 1500

Driver.FindElementById("ctl01_lnkCharacter", 5000, False).Click
```

In this case, the timeout is considered to be 1500 and not 5000 (I did this just to test) and the "False" is ignored, if it reaches the timeout there is an error alert.

In the instruction below it works:

```
Driver.Get url, 2000, False
```

It respects the timeout (2000) and if it is reached there is no error alert.

The problem is only in the `.click` statement.

When I use `.FindElementById(...).click` what is passed in the parameters as timeout and raise are ignored.

```
.FindElementById("ctl01_lnkCharacter", TIMEOUT, RAISE).click
```

I tried a variable, maybe it could works, for example

```
var = Driver.FindElementById("ctl01_lnkCharacter", 5000, False)
var.click
```

The variable is not accepted. The problem is not the timeout. I can pass the timeout before, explicitly.

The problem is the raise, I need to disable the error alert in case of timeout. Is there any other way to disable the error alert in case of timeout (without using On Error Resume Next).

The button is clicked correctly, the page opens correctly, but sometimes some images are loaded and I don't need to wait for the loading time and it takes a long time and this time varies a lot, while these images are loading it hits the timeout and generates the error.

That's why I need to disable the timeout error alert (raise parameter `False`).

Comment: Not sure if that will make a difference, but if you want to try using a variable, you need to add the keyword `set` in front of your variable name since FindElementById returns an `object`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, i already did, but unfortunately that's made no difference, same situation happened.